# Track only a percentage of users using tagmanager

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to track only a percentage of user on a website using tagmanager.
An easy way would be.

```
<script>
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
if ( rand == 1 ){
  alert('tag fired!');
}
```

Now this works but I need to make it better and want to track a user during is whole session. So the rand should be determined in the beginning of the session an stick to it.
So it should result track 10% of the users and not 10% of the pageviews.
Suggestions in how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is create a session cookie for those that are being tracked. Then you trigger your analytics tags off that cookie (whether it is `true` or `false`). Something as easy as `document.cookie = "track_me=true"`

I will say, are you trying to only launch GTM code snippets on the 10% of users, or just the analytic tags? If you don't want the code to even be placed on the page, then you might have programmatically deploy the container based on the rand value and the cookie.